# Can someone give me an example program algo in c#?

Tags: c#, binary

i want to write a program that tests if the string is a valid binary and converting it to decimal? below is my code that is not working properly

```
    private void BinarytoDecimal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = "";

        a = toBeConverted.Text;
        long y;
        y = Convert.ToInt64(a);
        for (int x = 0; x < a.Length; x++)
        {
            char h = a[x];
            if (h > '1' && h < '0')
            {
                MessageBox.Show("it is not a valid binary");
                break;
            }
            if(x == a.Length - 1)
            {
                long d = 0 , i = 0 , r , n;
                n = Convert.ToInt64(a);
                while (n != 0) {
                    r = n % 10;
                    n /= 10;
                    d += r * Math.Pow(2, i);
                    ++i;
                }

                labelConverted.Text = d.ToString() + " base10";


            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not `Convert.ToInt32("YourBinaryString", 2).ToString();`

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx for details on using conversion with a base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW its a one liner code to convert the Binary string into Decimal using

```
Convert.ToInt32("YourBinaryString", 2).ToString();
```

But, If you are looking it without LINQ than

```
var s = "101011";   //Your Binary String
var dec = 0;

var bl = Regex.Match(s, @"[-01]*");
if(s == bl.Value)
{
    for( int i=0; i<s.Length; i++ ) 
    {
        if( s[s.Length-i-1] == '0' ) 
            continue;

        dec += (int)Math.Pow( 2, i );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you give a perfectly acceptable answer in a comment and then provide this monstrosity as an answer? :-)

Comment: Bcoz the title says OP is looking for algo ... it seems OP want some formula to convert not directly convert it back. Just assumption

Comment: I'd remove references to LINQ since there's nothing in the one-liner that is LINQ-based. Perhaps "if you're looking for an algorithm rather than a one-liner" ?

Comment: Thanks  a lot guys :)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to check whether the input string is a valid binary number and also wanted to convert it to decimal right?

Following code will help you:

```
string inputStr = toBeConverted.Text;
if(inputStr.All(x=> x=='1' || x=='0')) // check all character is either 0 or 1
{
 // it is a valid binary
 string output = Convert.ToInt32(inputStr , 2).ToString(); 
}
else
{
    // Display message that not a valid binary
}
```

Comment: Isn't `-1001` valid binary? You'd probably be better off just catching the exception from `Convert()`.

Comment: @paxdiablo : cating exception from `Convert()` is a nice idea but `-1001` is not a valid binary value, `Convert.ToInt32("-101", 2)` throws errors

Comment: @AngeloMagnaye :  Happy to help you